# Clicking a link within nested tables using page-object

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a link that is nested withing layers of tables and most of the table do not have any id. The link that I have is under a  which is under a table that contains an id. I am unable to click the link no matter what. Here is the html. Please help. Thank you!

```
<html
 <frame src="my_frame"
   <html
    <table style="height:28px;"
     <table style="height:28px;"
      .
      .
       <table style="height:28px;"
         <table id="tblButtons"
           <td id="" title="" onmouseover="this.className = 'hdrBtn hdrBtnover';" onmouseout="this.className = 'hdrBtn';" onmousedown="this.className = 'hdrBtn hdrBtndown';" onmouseup="this.className = 'hdrBtn hdrBtnover';" background="../images/header/barbkg.gif" onclick="if(pageIsReady())parent.ordersummaryform.SubmitIt('OK');" class="hdrBtn"><a href="#" id="" class="linkForTabbingOnly" style="color:009900">Desktop</a></td>
             <a href="#" id="" class="linkForTabbingOnly" style="color:009900">Desktop</a>
```

I have tried using xpath as below:

```
link(  :desktop_header, :xpath => "a[@href='#' and @class='linkForTabbingOnly' and starts-with(text(),'Desktop')]")
```

and

```
link(  :desktop_header, :xpath => "//table[@id='tblButtons']//a[@href='#' and @class='linkForTabbingOnly' and starts-with(text(),'Desktop')]")
```

I also tried

I tried

`table(:table_button) {frame_element(:src => 'quotesummary_buttons.cfm?QuoteFormat=').table_element(:id => 'tblButtons',:href => '#', :class => 'linkForTabbingOnly' ) }`

`def click_desktop()
    table_button_element.cell_element(:class => 'hdrBtn')
    .child
    .link_element(:text => 'Desktop')
    .click
  end`

and used click_desktop to click the link but I get an error
NoMethodError: undefined method `frame_element' for #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your partial HTML and attempts, I would guess that the crux of the problem is the frame:

1. The first couple of attempts are not taking into account the frame. Unlike other elements, you have to specifically tell Watir when to look in a frame.
2. In one of the latter examples, the frame is considered. However, as the exception says, using `frame_element` does not exist for defining frames.

The [Page-Object gem wiki page](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Frames-and-iFrames) has a good explanation on how to work with frames.

The HTML provided seems a bit fragmented, so you may need to make some adjustments to the following suggestions. However, hopefully with the wiki page information and a couple of more specific examples, you can resolve your issue.

The first step would be to ensure that the link accessor is being told to look in a frame:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  in_frame(:src => 'my_frame') do |frame|
    link(:desktop_header, :href => '#', :class => 'linkForTabbingOnly', :text => /^Desktop/, :frame => frame)  
  end
end
```

Unless there are multiple links in the frame with text "Desktop", I would probably suggest simplifying the link locator to just the text - ie the href and class attributes do not appear to add anything.

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  in_frame(:src => 'my_frame') do |frame|
    link(:desktop_header, :text => 'Desktop', :frame => frame)
  end
end
```

If there are multiple "Desktop" links on the page, but only one such link in the "tblButtons" table, then you can use nesting. In the below example, the table is located within the scope of the frame by using the :frame locator. The link is then located within the table by using a block and the nested element methods.

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  in_frame(:src => 'my_frame') do |frame|
    table(:table_buttons, :id => 'tblButtons', :frame => frame)
    link(:desktop_header) { table_buttons_element.link_element(:text => 'Desktop') }
  end
end
```

While the concept of the above examples should work, there is a good chance that they will fail give the partial HTML provided. You might need to make some changes:

1. These examples assumed that the :src attribute of the frame is "my_frame", which is what is shown in the question's HTML sample. However, one attempts in the question suggest that the :src is actually "quotesummary_buttons.cfm?QuoteFormat=". Therefore, you should ensure that the correct :src (or other locator) is correct in the `in_frame(:src => 'my_frame')`.
2. That there is a `frame` element in the `html` element seems unusual. If I recall correctly, frames are only allowed in `frameset` elements. It maybe possible that you are actually dealing with an `iframe` instead of a `frame`. If so, you will need to change the `in_frame` methods to `in_iframe`. Note that either way, for the elements in the frame, the locator is still just `:frame`.

Comment: Thank you Justin. It was indeed a frame and not an iframe.  Sorry for replying late. I was not able to test because of the environment being down.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you should try to avoid using the xpath. It's very brittle and your code will likely break quite quickly!

Try nesting the elements such as:

```
@browser.table(:id, /Buttons/).link(:class, /link/)
```

I think you would really benefit from reading through the walk through of [defining different elements.](http://watirwebdriver.com/web-elements/) It's pretty helpful!